# How do I make messages on iPad stop interrupting my music

Tags: ipad, messages

I use messages on my mac and enable it on my ipad as well. When I play music (spotify) on ipad, it keeps getting interrupted by the iMessage. The interruption is the dimming of the sound. This is very annoying. How do I stop that?

Note that I don't want to stop imessage from coming in. But on the iPhone, when the phone is on silent and I am playing music, new messages don't disturb my music. I want that same functionality with the iPad.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do this by turning the iPad onto silent in a similar manner to iPhone. The difference is the side switch is configurable on iPad.

If you have the side switch set to "Lock Rotation" then:

1. Double tap the home button.
2. Swipe right.
3. Tap the sound icon to mute the device.

If you have the side switch set to "Mute" then:

1. Toggle the side switch like you do on iPhone.

You can change the side switch configuration in Settings.app -> General.